# PHP array problems - grouping array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to convert some array values (group then actually), but I don't know how to do that.

I have something like this:

```
[
 {
  "nsr": "000086310",
  "type": "3",
  "date": "2015-07-18",
  "time": "00:06",
  "pis": "12138790985"
 },
 {
  "nsr": "000086313",
  "type": "3",
  "date": "2015-07-18",
  "time": "00:33",
  "pis": "16073736879"
 },
 {
  "nsr": "000086316",
  "type": "3",
  "date": "2015-07-18",
  "time": "00:58",
  "pis": "16634402451"
 },
 {
  "nsr": "000086316",
  "type": "3",
  "date": "2015-07-19",
  "time": "00:58",
  "pis": "98127981729"
 },
 {
  "nsr": "000086316",
  "type": "3",
  "date": "2015-07-19",
  "time": "00:58",
  "pis": "12398712938"
 }
]
```

And I want to convert to this:

```
[
 "date" : "2015-07-18",
 "pis" : [
     "12138790985",
     "16073736879",
     "16634402451"
  ]
],
[
 "date" : "2015-07-19",
 "pis" : [
     "98127981729",
     "12398712938"
  ]
]
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $this->setTxtData('../../txt_files/CAP  3 18 07 2015 FABRICA.txt');
        $txtdata = $this->getTxtData();

        $dataToCompare = array();

        foreach($txtdata as $ponto){
            $time = $ponto['time'];
            $date = $ponto['date'];
            $pis = $ponto['pis'];

//            $dataToCompare = array();
//            if(strpos($ponto['pis'], '00000000000') === false){
//                $pis_temp[][''] = $ponto['pis'];
//            }

            if(isset($dataToCompare)){
                foreach($dataToCompare as $dateToSet){
                    if($dateToSet['data'] == $date){
                        $dateToSet['pis'][] = $pis;
                    }
                    else{
                        $dateToSet['data'] = $date;
                        $dateToSet['pis'][] = $pis;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                $dataToCompare = array(
                    [
                        'data' => $date,
                        'pis' => array($pis)
                    ]
                );
            }


            $funcionario_id = DB::table('funcionario')
                ->select('id')
                ->where('pis_pasep', '=', $pis)
                ->pluck('id');

            if($funcionario_id !== null){

                $validate = DB::table('horas_trabalho')
                    ->select('id')
                    ->where('hora', '=', $time)
                    ->where('data', '=', $date)
                    ->where('funcionario_id', '=', $funcionario_id)
                    ->pluck('id');

                if($validate === null){
                    DB::table('horas_trabalho')
                        ->insert([
                            'hora' => $time,
                            'data' => $date,
                            'funcionario_id' => $funcionario_id
                        ]);
                }
            }
        }

        //-------------------------------------Lógica para faltas-----------------------------------


        /**
         * Pega o pis
         */
        $db_all_funcionarios = DB::table('funcionario')
            ->select('pis_pasep')
            ->where('pis_pasep', '!=', 0)
            ->get();

        foreach($db_all_funcionarios as $pis){
            if(strpos($pis->pis_pasep, '00000000000') !== true){
                $global_pis[] = $pis->pis_pasep;
            }
        }

//        $faltantes = array_diff($pis_temp, $global_pis);

//        foreach($faltantes as $faltante){
//            DB::table('falta')
//                ->insert([
//                   'data' => date('2015-07-16')
//                ]);
//        }

//        $ponto_db[] = DB::table('horas_trabalho')
//            ->join('funcionario', 'horas_trabalho.funcionario_id', '=', 'funcionario.id')
//            ->select('funcionario.nome', 'horas_trabalho.hora', 'horas_trabalho.data')
//            ->get();



        return $txtdata;


    }
```

Comment: In what language? What have you tried?

Comment: PHP.

In this moment, I'm in a "I don't have no idea what I'm doing" moment. haha.

I'll copy/paste my code here. Just a sec.

Comment: Well, people won't write the code for you. It's always better to try and fail over not trying at all.

Comment: I know. Sorry to look like this. I actually did some work here. But nothing worked well...

Comment: It's not a problem, post your code that doesn't work. At least people can see why it isn't working and advise you on that.

Comment: That is it...
I'm working with Laravel 5.1, but I think it's not relevant.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Laravel myself. Tag your code with the laravel tag and hopefully somebody will be able to help.

Comment: But he want nothing to do with laravel here...

Comment: Exactly...the problem is to convert some data in array to another data organization in another array.

Comment: Like the first 2 examples that I wrote.

Comment: In your current example, all three have the same date. Can your input have more than one date? If so, you might want to update the sample input and output to show that.

Comment: Thank you guys! Sorry for anything...I'm new here! I Liked the way it works. It's like a "nerd" family solving problems together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the date in your filename and think you want group all entities at all:

```
$dataToCompare = array(
  'date' => $txtData[0]['date'],
  'pis' => array_map(function($el){return $el['pis'];}, $txtData)
);
```

For multiple dates:

```
$hash = array();
foreach ($txtData as $entity) {
  if (!isset($hash[$entity['date']])) $hash[$entity['date']] = array();
  $hash[$entity['date']][] = $entity['pis'];
}
$result = array();
foreach($hash as $date=>$pis) {
  $result[] = array('date'=>$date, 'pis'=>$pis);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, because the date is variable. I can't pick up only the first. But thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little sloppy, but it does the job. Or either way, it works as you wanted in the example:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    0 => array(
      "nsr" => "000086310",
      "type" => "3",
      "date" => "2015-07-18",
      "time" => "00:06",
      "pis" => "12138790985"
     ),
    1 => array(
      "nsr" => "000086313",
      "type" => "3",
      "date" => "2015-07-18",
      "time" => "00:33",
      "pis" => "16073736879"
     ),
     2 => array(
      "nsr" => "000086316",
      "type" => "3",
      "date" => "2015-07-18",
      "time" => "00:58",
      "pis" => "16634402451"
     )
 );
$newarray = array();
$pis = array();
foreach($array as $part){
        array_push($pis,$part['pis']);
        $newarray = array(
            "date" => $part['date'],
            "pis" => $pis
        );


}
var_dump($newarray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode($str, true);

// make array date => pis
$tmp = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
   if (!isset($tmp[$item['date']])) $tmp[$item['date']]['pis'] = array(); 
   $tmp[$item['date']]['pis'][] = $item['pis'];
}

// Than move date from key to item
$result = array();
foreach($tmp as $k=>$v) 
  $result[] = array('date' => $k, 'pis' => $v['pis']);
print_r($result);
```